How to write generic type for types extraction in Typescript
I am trying to extract types based on input type.
My code is:
type ArrayElement<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never;

interface Field {
    key: string;
    value: number | string;
    required?: boolean;
}

interface Props {
    test: number;
    fields: Field[];
}

type Rt<T extends Field> = Record<T['key'], T['value']>; 

const someFn = <T extends Field[]>(props: Props) => {
    const v = props.fields.reduce(
        (acc, vv) => ({
            ...acc,
            [vv.key]: vv.value,
        }),
        {},
    );

    return v as Rt<ArrayElement<T>>;
};

const p: Props = {
    test: 1,
    fields: [
        { key: 'name', value: 'John' },
        { key: 'age', value: 30 },
    ],
};

const r = someFn(p);

// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier, no-console
console.log(r.name, r.age); // name should be string type, age should be number type

Problem is, that return type is not perfect. My question is which Typescript operators should I use for correct extraction from Field type. Name should be string type, age should be number type.
Right now both of my variables are union type string | number.
What is wrong with my code?
I tried to create custom type and this type is described in my question.

Once p is annotated as Props, the more specific literal type information is already lost. p.fields will need to be typed as a tuple of objects with literal values in order to infer those literals at another site.

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?
